# Trouble installing opencv in docker container using pip

Tags: python, opencv, docker

I want to build a python docker container that has scikit-learn, opencv, and numpy. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a pre-built container that contained all these, but I did find the one below that contains numpy and scikit-learn.

https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-python-machinelearning/

I still needed to install opencv, so within my docker file I included a `RUN pip install opencv-python`. However, I keep on getting the error below:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from version: ) 
No matching distribution found for opencv-python`

Every single thing I have read online says that a `pip install opencv-python` will work, but it isn't working for me for some reason. Is it a problem with the python package maybe?

Any help is appreciated

Also, I will include my full Dockerfile below, I am aiming to use openFaas, which is a serverless framework, so my Dockerfile might look odd:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-python-machinelearning

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade

# Alternatively use ADD https:// (which will not be cached by Docker builder)
RUN apk --no-cache add curl \
    && echo "Pulling watchdog binary from Github." \
    && curl -sSL         
https://github.com/openfaas/faas/releases/download/0.8.0/fwatchdog > /usr/bin/fwatchdog \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/fwatchdog \
    && apk del curl --no-cache

# Add non root user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S -g app app
RUN chown app /home/app

RUN pip install -U pip

USER app

ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/app/.local/bin

WORKDIR /home/app/

RUN pip install opencv-python

RUN mkdir -p function
RUN touch ./function/__init__.py
WORKDIR /home/app/function/
RUN pip install --user app opencv-python

WORKDIR /home/app/
COPY function           function

ENV fprocess="python index.py"

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1s CMD [ -e /tmp/.lock ] || exit 1

CMD ["fwatchdog"]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've just run into this issue as well.  It turns out that this is not working because `opencv-python` does not have any prebuilt wheels for Alpine (the distribution you're using as your base docker image).

The conversation in [this](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/75) issue on the `opencv-python` package explains why this happens in greater detail.  The TL;DR is: if you really need to use Alpine, you can try [forcing the installation](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3969) of the manylinux wheel for `opencv-python`, but this can break.  Your best option if you need to keep Alpine is to build the module from source.  Since you are running this on OpenFAAS, I suspect you will want to keep your size low, so building from source may be a good option for you.

If you're not attached to Alpine, I would suggest moving to a different base docker image.  If you're not sure which image to use as your base, I would recommend `python:3.9-slim`, since it will come with Python already installed (substitute `3.9` for a newer version if this no longer works).  With this container, you can simply run `pip install opencv-python numpy scipy` to have all three of your desired packages installed.  The rest of your Dockerfile should work mostly unmodified; you will just need to install/uninstall `curl` using `apt` instead of `apk`.

Additionally, you will need to install a couple extra packages in order to actually use opencv.  Be sure to add `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libgl1-mesa-glx && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` to your `Dockerfile` so the shared libraries that OpenCV depends on are present in the container image.

Comment: ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, 
I get this error switching to  `slim` from `alpline`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  The install succeeds, but I also see this error when running `import cv2` in python inside this container.  I have found a way to fix this and I will update my answer with the additional requirements.

Comment: @rnorris getting same issue while importing cv2 in python, how did you fix it?

Comment: @MuhammadUzair, Did the last paragraph not fix this for you?  If not, you can open a new question with a detailed error message and I can take a look.

Comment: I went with `python3.9-slim` as base image & it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, but even more complicated by requiring an ARMv7 image (as this was supposed to run on a Raspberry Pi). I've put together a Dockerfile and a pre-built OpenCV installation here: [alpine-opencv-docker](https://github.com/janjongboom/alpine-opencv-docker).

Alternatively you can compile yourself in the Dockerfile, but this takes a huge amount of time (probably close to a full day), via:

```
ENV OPENCV_VER 3.3.0
ENV OPENCV https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VER}.tar.gz

# build dependencies
RUN apk add -U --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies \
    build-base \
    clang \
    clang-dev ninja \
    cmake \
    freetype-dev \
    g++ \
    jpeg-dev \
    lcms2-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libgcc \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    linux-headers \
    make \
    musl \
    musl-dev \
    openjpeg-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    python3-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    curl \
    freetype \
    gcc \
    jpeg \
    libjpeg \
    openjpeg \
    python3 \
    tesseract-ocr \
    zlib

# build opencv from source
RUN mkdir /opt && cd /opt && \
    curl -L $OPENCV | tar zx && \
    cd opencv-$OPENCV_VER && \
    mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -G Ninja \
          -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
          -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
          -D WITH_FFMPEG=NO \
          -D WITH_IPP=NO \
          -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
          -D WITH_OPENEXR=NO .. && \
    ninja && ninja install && \
    cp -p $(find /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages -name cv2.*.so) \
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
```

I pulled together my package by compiling the above in a huge EC2 VM, then pulling the following paths off the container:

- /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.so
- /usr/local/include/opencv
- /usr/local/include/opencv2
- /usr/local/lib

Then I can add them back via normal `ADD` commands in my Dockerfile, so now everyone who wants to spin up the container is done in seconds instead of days.

Answer (score 4):

I found this article, [Using Alpine can make Python Docker builds 50x slower](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/), to be very helpful when dealing with this issue. Here is an excerpt from it:

> ... standard Linux wheels don’t work on Alpine Linux.
>
> Why? Most Linux distributions use the GNU version (glibc) of the
>   standard C library that is required by pretty much every C program,
>   including Python. But Alpine Linux uses musl, those binary wheels are
>   compiled against glibc, and therefore Alpine disabled Linux wheel
>   support.
>
> Most Python packages these days include binary wheels on PyPI,
>   significantly speeding install time. But if you’re using Alpine Linux
>   you need to compile all the C code in every Python package that you
>   use.
>
> Which also means you need to figure out every single system library
>   dependency yourself.

Hopefully this adds to the comment/recommendation from [rnorris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474814/10589271) to use a different base image (if you're not married to Alpine).

The article was very helpful to me in debugging this issue. I hope it is for you as well!

Answer (score 3):

Using  `python:3.7-alpine`, I was just able to install both `numpy` and `opencv-utils`. The only change I needed to make was to add `g++` as additional package to my apk command in Dockerfile

```
RUN apk --no-cache add g++ ${ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE}
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this https://hub.docker.com/r/jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv

it's Docker image with python 3.7 and opencv 4.1.0

```
docker run -it jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv python
>>> import cv2
```

then you can install `opencv-python==4.1.2.30` by pip.

Comment: It's updated to python 3.9 now. Not so good if you want to use it with Tensorflow as of January 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip

pip3 install opencv-python

source > https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/1213#issuecomment-703272203